# Solving Feedback Vertex Set (FVS) in FPT time $5^k$ with iterative compression?

Tags: fixed-parameter-tractable

I understand that Disjoint Feedback Vertex Set (= looking for a solution $X$ of size $k$ given a solution $W$ of size $k+1$ s.t. $X \subseteq V \setminus W$ ) can be solved in time $4^k poly(n)$, see 4.3 [here](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf).

They also say FVS can be solved in $5^k poly(n)$ using iterative compression with the DFVS algorithm, but I can't see how.
If I start with a $2$-approximation, the total runtime would be $5^{2k} poly(n)$ by iterating over all subsets of a given solution as $W$ and executing the DFVS algorithm for each.

What is the starting point for the iterative compression and how does it lead to the given runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, it is also mentioned in the [book](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf) in chapter 4.1.

We start by taking a subgraph with $k+1$ arbitrary vertices instead of the whole graph, so the whole vertex set is a $k+1$-solution. Then we do DFVS with every subset to obtain a $k$-solution. Finally we add another vertex from the original graph to our current subgraph (and current solution) and repeat.

Thus each step takes $5^kpoly(n)$ time and we do $n$ iterations.